# Kendo Editor Templates (Grid)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to populate a dropdownlist for use in my Kendo Grid using [Editor Templates](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates).

My StatesEditor.cshtml contains:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("State") 
.DataValueField("StateID") 
.DataTextField("ShortName") 
.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["states"]))
```

In my Controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new ACoreEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var states = db.StateLookups;

        var stateList = states.Select(state => state.ShortName);

        ViewData["states"] = stateList;


        return View("~/Views/System/PMarkup/Index.cshtml");
    }
```

In my actual grid, when I click the 'Edit' button for the row I get a dropdownlist that contains 51 'undefined' entries.

Comment: https://kendoeditortemplate.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a State model then in my ActionResult I changed my code to:

```
ViewData["states"] = new ACoreEntities()
            .StateLookups
            .Select(s => new State
            {
                Id = s.StateID,
                ShortName = s.ShortName
            })
            .OrderBy(s => s.ShortName);
```